# Converting a date and time string into a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I have a date time in string format like this:
Example 1: 2021-06-09T02:00:00+01:00
Example 2: 2021-06-09T02:00:00+00:00

What I'd like to do is convert this into UTC and store in a DateTime.

I thought I could do something like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(stringDate, "yyyy-MM-dd\"T\"HH:mm:ss:zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But this is not working as it says the string is not in a valid date time format. Is anyone able to help please?

Answer (score 2):

You have a mistake in your format string. It should be `"yyyy-MM-dd\"T\"HH:mm:sszzz"` to match your example date time strings.

Comment: Doh...sorry, silly mistake. Thank you.